# Postgresql: how to return a single column request as an integer array

Tags: postgresql

I would like to create a function that returns a column of a table as an integer array.

In other words, how can I transfrom the result of `SELECT id FROM mytable` to integer[] ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
SELECT ARRAY(SELECT id FROM mytable)
```

Or:

```
SELECT array_agg(id) FROM mytable
```

Comment: The array constructor is typically faster than the aggregate function (which is more versatile and works for multiple rows also).